# Pass google maps instance to another activity

Tags: java, android

I need to pass an instance of google maps(mMap) in MapsActivity to another activity (TravelsActivit) but I can't do that using an Intent, how could I do it?

```
case R.id.lista_viagens_ativas:
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViagensAtivasActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("mapa", mMap);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
```

Comment: _why_ do you need to pass this instance over ? explain your problem as well as your attempted solution, usually there's more than one way to achieve something

Comment: I need to pass an instance of the map to another activity to update the camera when choosing a trip, and I also need to pass a travel list, the list I can pass using intent but the map doesn't

Comment: updating the camera usually requires a position for it to go to, have you considered passing around the information needed to move the camera instead of the entire object ?

Comment: yes it needs a latitude and longitude but i need the map where the camera will be updated ..

Comment: depending on what `mMap` is , you can also consider making it static and just using it where you need it to, but your question is lacking detail, hard to find a solution without being able to see entirely what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I need an interface to share data between activities, how can I do it?
mMap is instance of GoogleMaps:

Comment: "I need to pass an instance of google maps(mMap) in MapsActivity to another activity (TravelsActivit)" -- if you mean [the `GoogleMap` object](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap), AFAIK what you want is not practical. AFAIK, the `GoogleMap` object is tied to the `MapView` or `MapFragment` that provided it to you.

Comment: You must use MapView or fragment to each Activity that you want to show map on this.